# Парсинг принтеров

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt, qt5

Помогите распарсить эту сроку:
интересуют такие параметры на название принтера и дата установки

```
HP_LaserJet aceepting requests since Вт. 28 февр. 2017 17:49:12 HP_LaserJet aceepting requests since Вт. 28 февр. 2017 17:49:12
```

Comment: а что, данные в строке обязательно дублируются?

Comment: Нет не обязательно, название принтера и дата могут быть любыми

Comment: Зачем здесь вообще регулярные выражения? Достаточно обычного `scanf`/`sscanf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярное выражение под вашу строку выглядит так:

```
[^ ]+\ aceepting\ requests\ since\ (?:Пн|Вт|Ср|Чт|Пт|Сб|Вс)\.\ \d+\ (?:янв|февр|март|апр|май|июнь|июль|авг|сен|окт|нояб|дек)\.?\ \d{4}\ \d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}
```

Рабочий пример: https://regex101.com/r/xWB0u4/1